# I read Asimov's Foundation trilogy. Which Foundation novel should I tackle next?

Tags: suggested-order, isaac-asimov, foundation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What order should Asimov’s Foundation series be read in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/what-order-should-asimovs-foundation-series-be-read-in)

I recently read Asimov's Foundation Trilogy (i. e. *Foundation*, *Foundation and Empire* and *Second Foundation*. I especially enjoyed the plot twists at the end of *Second Foundation*.

Which Foundation novel do you recommend me to read next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've already read this amazing series, so I can answer:

First two books is a Prequel (but!, this two books were written almost 5-10 years after the original pentalogy were published):

1. Prelude to Foundation
2. Forward the Foundation

The main pentalogy:

1. Foundation
2. Foundation and Empire
3. Second Foundation
4. Foundation's Edge
5. Foundation and Earth

That's how I read and how the plot is developed.

So, about what to read next, I think the best would be read the *Foundation's Edge* and before reading *Foundation and Earth* read the two *Prequel* books.

**PS:** Consider looking [here](http://www.goodreads.com/series/59386-foundation-publication-order) and [here](http://www.goodreads.com/series/49421-foundation-universe).

Comment: So would you recommend me to go back to the first prequel *Prelude to Foundation* instead of continuing the main pentalogy with *Foundation's Edge*, right?

Comment: @Dominik: True. I've updated the answer. That's, I think, the best way I think (anyway, the *Robots* series can make some things clearer).

Answer (score 4):

I would read the next written, namely *Foundation's Edge*.

The final book *Foundation and Earth* and the prequels *Prelude to Foundation* and *Forward the Foundation* make a lot more sense once you have read the Robot series.