# The Empire novels of Isaac Asimov

Tags: isaac-asimov, empire

Which is the first Empire novel of I Asimov, "The stars like dust" or "the currents of space"?

Comment: I think it's a duplicate (this has already been asked on this site) but can't find the question atm

Comment: It has, on several occasions - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/what-order-should-asimovs-foundation-series-be-read-in/2862#2862

Comment: Using the criteria of 'It is fully answer via the answered to another question', yeah -- dup, with this answer: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2862/2292  -- The question isn't actually a duplicate, but the answer is within the answer to the linked question.

Comment: [Empire series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Empire_%28series%29) != [Foundation series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_series), although the answer you link does provide the answer to this.

Comment: I'm unsure about the dupe. Would someone looking for the order of the _Empire_ novels think of reading the answers to a question about the _Foundation_ novels? I know I wouldn't if I wasn't already familiar with Asimov (in which case I wouldn't need to ask the question at all).

Comment: The most popular answers to that question are contradictory, as is much of the information on the internet about it. A more thorough answer about these 2 books order would be beneficial. Many sources say The Stars, Like Dust is the first, many others say The Currents of Space is the first one. Even the most popular answer here contradicts the answer in the linked question!

Answer (score 12):

The order of publication is:

1. Pebble in the Sky (1950)
2. The Stars, Like Dust (1951)
3. The Currents of Space (1952)

However in order of chronology is:

1. The Stars, Like Dust
2. The Currents of Space
3. Pebble in the Sky

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Empire_%28series%29)

Comment: @user14111: Actually, the publication order is not questionable at all, since _Pebble in the Sky_ was first published as a [Doubleday book](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?188181), which, according to Asimov's autobiography _In Memory Yet Green_, was officially published on January 19, 1950. The issue of Galaxy containing the first part of _The Stars, Like Dust_ aka _Tyrann_ hit the newsstands almost a full year later, in December 1950 (again according to _IMYG_).

Comment: Several people share your order of chronology. Why is it that Asimov suggested reading The Currents of Space first? Any idea?

Comment: Apparently by mistake, falsely thinking it came first in fictional chronology.

In The Stars Like Dust everybody knows that the radioactive Earth is humanity's  home world. Only part of the galaxy has been colonized yet.

In The Currents of Space all the galaxy is explored & settled for centuries or millennia. The planet Trantor has been discovered since  The Stars Like Dust, and settled and advanced  enough to conquer half the galaxy.

Comment: Earth is merely one candidate for humanity's home planet in the Currents of Space.

And in Pebble in the Sky Trantor has united all the galaxy and become the Galactic Empire over 700 years ago. Only Earth men claim that Earth is the original home of humans. A project begins to remove earth's radioactivity.  So even the author can sometimes forget the correct fictional chronology & order of his stories.