# Is there any certain chronological order of all of Isaac Asimov's series, novels and short stories that Isaac Asimov himself specified?

Tags: suggested-order, isaac-asimov

Even though that there are many recommended personal reading orders about Isaac Asimov's series, novels and short stories, is there any specific chronological order which was specified by Isaac Asimov about his books?

Comment: [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/24540/70236) is what you need.

Comment: Note also that it may not be the optimal order, as suggested in comments to that answer.