# Star Trek: TNG novels that continue episodes?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, star-trek-eu

In the original series episode, *"All Our Yesterdays"*, Spock goes back in time 4000 years into a particular planet's history.

Two sequels to this episode were written as novels. *"Yesterday's Son"* and *"Time for Yesterday"*  in which it is revealed, among other things, that:

> Spock had a son with that nice cave lady.

I am wondering which episodes of *The Next Generation* have similar sequels or prequels, and is there a comprehensive list of such things, perhaps including all the series?

Comment: This seems suspiciously close to a question looking for a listing and/or recommendation, both of which are generally frowned upon in the [FAQ](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-science-fiction-and-fantasy-related-questions)

Comment: Not at all. I'm looking for a definitive list of novels that continue story arcs from aired episodes of the television show.

Comment: Exactly. `Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here: ... Questions calling for a list of works, authors, ...: What are all the books that have X? Who wrote about topic Y?`

Comment: My question seems to be in the more-accepted "Questions where the answer has a small number of items, which might be presented as a list" at least according to the [Meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic). The examples in your comment are open-ended and would result in a limitless number of answers each presenting only some of the possible answers.  There are a finite number of Star Trek novels and my question could be answered by one person providing a complete list.

Comment: There are several such extensions for TOS; I'd be surprised if there were none for TNG.

Comment: Interesting. I hate list questions and mercilessly vote to close them, but this one is answerable with a finite list and the answers will not be opinion-based. Looks good to me.

Comment: The danger of such questions is that we can wind up with a large quantity of answers that each only provide a small part of the overall answer. No offense to Flimzy, but a list of 20 separate answers, each listing one or two examples of what the OP is looking for, is precisely the reason why lists of works are off-topic. I agree that a good answer could be given, but it still invites noise and discussion.

Comment: @Beofett - As I indicated, I would usually agree, but not in this case. Downvote the bad answers, then, or flag them as "not an answer". And there's no reason not to take a bunch of incomplete answers and write a new, comprehensive answer summarizing them.

Comment: @neilfein the new answer summarizing them would not necessarily be complete. Also, on the topic of this being a finite list... are Star Trek novels still being published?

Comment: @Beofett - Yes, they are still being published. But by the "finite list" logic, we shouldn't allow any questions that have lists of works, including reading order questions. (For example, there's gonna be a new trilogy of robot novels, making [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/832/asimov-start-with-foundation-or-robots/6223#6223) outdated.)

Comment: But it looks like this is going to be closed anyway. (I generally feel that, when in doubt, close the question.)

Comment: If you're into Klingons, the novel "Diplomatic Implausibility" uses characters from pretty much EVERY Klingon-related TNG episode.

Answer (score 5):

There are quite a few TNG novels which reuse guest characters but I'm not going to list those since I don't really see those as sequels.

These are the novels that I feel are very strongly sequels to TNG episodes:

- [**Dyson Sphere**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671541730): this novels revisits the Dyson Sphere seen in the episode Relics.
- [**Imzadi**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671867296): this novel tells the story of Troi and Riker's relationship before TNG. The novel takes place before TNG as well as the episode All Good Things and the "future" seen in that episode.

These novels aren't really sequels but are fairly tightly woven into the TNG fabric:

- [**The Double Helix series**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743412729): these books depict a series of biological weapons developed over a huge amount of time. The novels themselves span from the time of Jean Luc Picard's command of the Stargazer to the New Frontier era.

Answer (score 1):

The Star Trek TOS episode [*Mirror, Mirror*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror,_Mirror_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)) has a sequel novel set in the TNG universe called [*Dark Mirror*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671794388), which I read many years ago and enjoyed at the time.

Comment: That's not so much a sequel to a specific episode as a novel exploring the mirror universe concept.

Comment: @neilfein: That would mean that TNG isn't a sequel to TOS, or that Wrath of Khan isn't a sequel to the Motion Picture. It seems that this novel is much more a sequel than these other two, by most measures.

Comment: I think that Wrath of Khan is more of a sequel to the episode "Space Seed" than TMP. But all this comes down to what the question author is looking for: TNG-era sequels to anything, or sequels to TNG episodes specifically? (From the question, it seems like the latter.)

Comment: @neilfein The mirror universe story arc has a single continuity starting with "Mirror, Mirror": *Dark Mirror* is definitely a sequel to the episode, as are "[Crossover](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Crossover_%28episode%29)", "[Through the Looking Glass](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Through_the_Looking_Glass)", "[Shattered Universe](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Shattered_Mirror)", "[Resurrection](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Resurrection)", and "[The Emperor's New Cloak](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Cloak)".

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen such a list on the web, but if I remember correctly the "*The Q Continuum*" books are interlaced with the episodes featuring Q.

Comment: Correct. Or at least, they make reference to plot elements from those episodes, such as the Tkon Empire, and the Calamarain. See [this from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Q_Continuum) for more info.